# How to perform calculation in object array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am performing calculation in nested object array in javascript.
I have two inputs as shown

for the `obj` 
if `obj.rate > mr` then

`cr =  (((obj.amount * obj.rate) - (obj.amount * mr))/(obj.amount * obj.rate))*100 + "%",
totalcost =  (obj.netfee-(cr*amountwithfee)`

if `obj.rate < mr` then

`cr =  (((obj.amount * mr) - (obj.amount * obj.rate))/(obj.amount * mr))*100 + "%",
totalcost =  (obj.netfee+(cr*amountwithfee)`

How to do the above calculation in below function in precise manner

```
  var result = obj.forEach(e=>{
     ..obj,
     netfee: obj.fee + obj.payfee,
     amountwithfee: obj.amount-obj.netfee,
     cr: (((obj.amount * mr) - (obj.amount * obj.rate))/(obj.amount * mr))*100 + "%",
     totalcost: (obj.netfee+(cr*amountwithfee); 
  })
 console.log(result);
```

Inputs

```
  var mr = 0.5;
  var obj =[{
    amount: 1000,
    fee: 5,
    payfee:2,
    rate:0.49
  }]
```

Expected output:

```
  result = [{
    amount: 1000,
    fee: 5,
    payfee: 2,
    netfee: 7, 
    amountwithfee: 993,
    rate: 0.49,
    cr : -2%, 
    totalcost: 26.86
  }]
```

Comment: This is confusing because you are calling `obj.forEach ` but `obj` is not an array.  Also `forEach()` doesn't return anything. Are you starting with an object or an array of objects?

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks for reply, sorry, its array of objects. updated code

Answer (score 0):

```js
//initiallizing
var mr = 0.5;

var obj =[
    {
      amount: 1000,
      fee: 5,
      payfee:2,
      rate:0.49
    },
    {
      amount: 1000,
      fee: 5,
      payfee:2,
      rate:0.5
    }
];

var result = [];

//start calculation
obj.forEach(x => {

     let netfee = 0;
     let amountwithfee = 0;
     let cr = 0;
     let totalcost = 0;

     netfee = x.fee + x.payfee;
     amountwithfee = x.amount- netfee;

     //write your login
     if (x.rate < mr) {
       cr = (((x.amount * mr) - (x.amount * x.rate))/(x.amount * mr))*100;
       totalcost = (netfee + (cr * amountwithfee)); 
     } 
     else
     {
       cr = (((x.amount * x.rate) - (x.amount * mr))/(x.amount * x.rate))*100;
       totalcost = (netfee - (cr * amountwithfee));         
     }
     
     //generate output
     result.push({
        'amount': x.amount,
        'fee': x.fee,
        'payfee': x.payfee,
        'netfee': netfee,
        'amountwithfee': amountwithfee,
        'rate': x.rate,
        'cr': cr + "%",
        'totalcost': totalcost
     });

});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

While doing the mathematical calculations use `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` wherever it's required or use `eval()` for the operations.

Comment: I won't ever recommend to use `eval()`. I will be able to execute any js I want to.